# openCV blur image

Tags: python, python-3.x

Get the following message: `TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'`

I do not know why it is not working. Any ideas?

```
# Load picture as a numpy array
import cv2
image = cv2 . imread ("beatles.jpg")
image = cv2 . cvtColor ( image , cv2 . COLOR_BGR2RGB )

# See that it is working 
print (image)
cv2.imshow("Bilde", image)
cv2.waitKey (5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

# Box Blur kernel
box_kernel = [[1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9]]
kernel = box_kernel

cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)
```

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Comment: post the full stack trace, this will improve your chance to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import numpy as np
box_kernel = np.array([[1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9]])
```

[From the examples in the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html), it seems that you must give your kernel as a numpy `ndarray`. I suspect this has to do with the fact that OpenCV is written in C/C++, where arguments are passed into `filter2D` by reference or pointer instead of by value. In Python there's no way to do this with a `list`, but numpy's `ndarray` uses C under the hood, and OpenCV's Python interface probably has a way to pass it into C/C++ code.